# Biometric Prompt SubTitle text getting truncated on Android

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I have implemented biometric authentication where my subtitle(Verify biometrics for username to Sign In to My **App Name**) is a bit long and it's getting truncated at the end this is happening mainly on Samsung Devices.
Any limits on character length or OEM issue any idea how to fix.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They have to come up with a solution on this since we can't control it, it's by default.
I faced the same issue but switched to use :

```
.setDescription("")
```

Keep in mind that this will remove the system hints : scan your fingerprint or use face recognition. For the moment with what i've tried is the only solution, until they come up with a fix regarding it.

Comment: I had submitted the issue ticket to Samsung and they were able to reproduce it and assigned it to the respective team.

Comment: Nice job, thanks @Girish for letting me know.

Comment: Any update on this issue @Girish

Comment: @AsifBanarasDhamial this should be fixed now