# BiometricPrompt description is truncated in Android 12

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric, android-12

The only related thing I can see from the [Android 12 new features/API added in android documentation is "Localizeable strings for BiometricPrompt"](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features#biometric-prompt)

My problem is illustrated in the image below and code looks something like

```
    BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
     .setTitle(title)
     .setSubtitle(optional) //have tried to use this but same issue with description
     .setDescription(necessarilyLongDescriptionHere)
     .setConfirmationRequired(true)
```

[image]

A `<br>` or a `\n` does not work here too.

Has anyone encountered this? And have a reliable solution?

Comment: Looks like you are not the only one with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/66353830/2070800

Comment: Since the prompt is supplied by the device manufacturer, you should not be making any assumptions that your title, subtitle, or description are displayed *at all*, let alone displayed entirely.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I’m still wondering what causes the issue since it’s displayed correctly on an android version lower than 12